# How to fetch data of selected movie to detailActivity and then to fragments in detail activity?

Tags: java, android

1. NowShowingFragment.java

   ```
      nowShowingAdapter = new NowShowingAdapter(nowShowingMovieList, new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                               Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MovieDetailActivity.class);
                                   intent.putExtra("movie",nowShowingMovieList.get(position));
                                   startActivity(intent);
   ```
2. It leads to the Detail Activity  (MovieDetailActivity.java)

   ```
           private Movie selectedMovie ;


               selectedMovie = (Movie) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("movie");

               int movieId = selectedMovie.getMovieId();


               Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
               bundle.putString("language", selectedMovie.getMovieLanguage());
               bundle.putString("duration", selectedMovie.getMovieDuration());
               bundle.putString("director", selectedMovie.getMovieDirector());
               bundle.putString("genre", selectedMovie.getMovieGenre());
               bundle.putString("description", selectedMovie.getMovieDescription());
               bundle.putSerializable("selected", selectedMovie);

               // set MyFragment Arguments
               NowShowingFragment movieObject = new NowShowingFragment();
               movieObject.setArguments(bundle);
   ```
3. It contains 3 fragments these are:
   i) MovieInformationFragment.java

   ```
       public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

               tvMovieLanguage = view.findViewById(R.id.tvMovieLanguage);
               tvMovieGenre = view.findViewById(R.id.tvMovieGenre);
               tvMovieDirector = view.findViewById(R.id.tvMovieDirector);
               tvMovieDuration = view.findViewById(R.id.tvMovieDuration);

               tvMovieLanguage.setText(this.getArguments().getString("language"));
               tvMovieGenre.setText(this.getArguments().getString("genre"));
               tvMovieDirector.setText(this.getArguments().getString("director"));
               tvMovieDuration.setText(this.getArguments().getString("duration"));
   ```

ii)MovieDescriptionFragment.java
It contains the story line of the movie.

```
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            tvMovieDescription = view.findViewById(R.id.tvMovieDescription);

            tvMovieDescription.setText(this.getArguments().getString("description"));

        }
```

iii)MovieCastFragment.java
It contains the actor images and names of the selected movie.

```
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            mContext = getContext();
            progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            rvMoviecast = view.findViewById(R.id.rvMoviecast);

            Serializable castArray = getArguments().getSerializable("selectedMovie");

        }
```

MovieCastFragment consist of MovieCastAdapter because I have used recycler view in it.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull movieCastHolder holder, int position) {

        Context context = holder.itemView.getContext();

        Picasso.get().load(dataset.get(position).getActorImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder).into(holder.ivActorImage);
        holder.tvActorName.setText(dataset.get(position).getActorName());


    }
```

all of these fragments are managed by the MovieDetailPagerAdapter.java  I have posted its code below as:

```
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                if (position==0){
                    return new MovieInfromationFragment();
                }else if(position==1){
                    return new MovieCastFragment();
                }else if(position==2){
                    return new MovieDescriptionFragment();
                }
                return null;
            }
```

Comment: I have used this json having movieArray which contains castArray which contains actorArray. I have to fetch data. I have detail activity containing three fragments where I want to show the selected movie details.

Comment: You must get the list using asynctask or retrofit or somthing similar

Comment: Can I not use the bundle to pass the data? I am using Gson, but having error to fetch data. It shows reference on null object.

Comment: Hi -- can you edit your question so that it actually has a question in it? You seem to have put your requirement in a comment.

Comment: Really sorry, If it seems like that, I don't get appropriate words to express my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just fetch the data using retrofit and store it in the list of MoviesData and to show the specific movie's details in the DetailActivity, pass that movie object as extra to that activity. Just like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ItemDetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("selectedMovie", selectedMovie);
startActivity(intent);
```

Here, selectedMovie is the movie object which you wanna show in DetailActivity.

And then to share that movie detail to the fragment try this:

```
Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
arguments.putParcelable("selectedMovie", selectedMovie);
MovieDetailFragment fragment = new MovieDetailFragment();
fragment.setArguments(arguments);
this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
       .replace(R.id.movie_detail_container, fragment)
       .commit();
```

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks for coment!Yes I have pass the data to the detail activity. But from detail activity I want to pass data to fragments in detail activity. And one of the fragment is of Actors in Movie. But don't know how to fetch the actors of selected movie in that fragment.

Comment: I edited my answer that how to pass data to the fragment in DetailActivity and for the details of actors of selected movie, as per my assumption from the above data that also coming and storing to the movie object as list of cast. you can directly get from it.

Comment: Thank you. But how to use it in fragment?

Comment: Same procedure. Pass the list of cast to the fragment as a bundle and retrive that in fragment and then pass it to the adapter to display.

Answer (score 0):

Since you provided no code, I will answer without code assuming you are getting that json from the network

1- You must get the json list asynchronously using asynctask or retrofit or somthing similar

2- create a movie object and use somthing like gson to convert the json to that object

3-Use things like intent or  better ViewModel to share the data between views
[The documentation for ViewModel is easy to follow and includes example for exactly what you want](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

4- Optionally store the data in sqlite for offline usage